# Why are thermoluminescent materials mostly mostly based on calcium sulfate rather than on zinc sulfide or calcium fluoride?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure

I am doing a research in thermo-luminiscent topic and over a part of phosphor called calcium sulfate? The question my mentor asked to me is that why mostly people choose calcium sulfate to do research on and why not other phosphor parts like zinc sulfide or calcium fluoride? Is there something special about calcium sulfate or it is easy to do research over it because he said that he observed in his career that mostly people let it teachers or professors or students will do research over calcium sulfate and not on zinc sulfide or calcium fluoride.

Comment: In what kind of research? Could you be more specific?

Comment: The question is wrong in its premises, and you should be able to recognize it as such. This world is wide, wide indeed; by no means is it limited to one, or two, or three, or even _four_ compounds. Many are used in research. Then again, there is another possibility: maybe you are telling us only a _half_ of the question?

Comment: @Ivan Neretin  Dear sir, I am doing a research in thermoluminiscent topic and over a part of phosphor called calcium sulphate? The question my mentor asked to me is that why mostly people choose calcium sulphate to do research on and why not other phosphor parts like zns or calcium fluoride? Is there something special about calcium sulphate or it is easy to do research over it because he said that he observed in his career that mostly people let it teachers or professors or students will do research over calcium sulphate and not on zns or calcium fluoride.

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, **pure(!)** calcium sulfate does not show thermoluminescence.

It is however true that it can be turned into thermoluminescent materials by **doping** with rare metals, such as dysprosium or terbium.

According to a [conference contribution](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/37/121/37121599.pdf), $\ce{CaSO4:Dy}$ is prepared from calcium sulfate and dysprosium oxide in concentrated sulfuric acid at temperatures between 200 and 300 °C.

While calcium sulfate will survive these reaction conditions, other base materials, such as calcium fluoride or zinc sulfide, will rather not.